# Count function calls by name or signature. Gcc, C++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, profiling, gdb

I have some c++ written package. Linux, gcc. I can modify compilation process (change Makefile, flags, etc.), but can **not** change C++ source code.

One runs the package with different parameters, it does a job and exits.

How to **count**:
1) Number of calls of function with specific name?
2) Number of calls of functions with specific signature?
3) Number of calls of functions where one of the parameters is of specific type i.e. std::string (type is specified by signature)?
4) and *extra* Number of calls of functions of STL objects, i.e. std::string copy constructor?

(I mean count a number of calls during the run. )

I thought to do it with GDB, but I found it very tough to do (1) and have not found how to do (2)-(4) at all.

---

All acceptable answers I will write here for humanity.

Comment: Humanity appreciates it!

Comment: Well, I feel funny recommending it, but isn't all this counting something that `gprof` is actually good at?

Comment: It can count, but when you have names and counts you have to somehow "connect" your desired functions with it. I mean that (1) is easy to achieve. But how i.e. to connect calls of functions with specified argument type with function names that gprof actually returns? For now I see it to be too complex. If there is an easy way extracting it from gprof, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't gprof show de-mangled names? They may not be easy to read, because the expanded datatypes get really lengthy, but `void foo(int)` and `void foo(double)` are not one function, they are two (in C++) with separate invocation counts. It sounds like that's what you want, unless I misunderstand.

Answer (score 4):

You can try running [DTRACE](http://blogs.oracle.com/ahl/entry/dtrace_for_linux) under linux. It's definitely a great tool for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked Valgrind's [callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html)?

If you are not using threading (or are willing to experiment a bit), [gprof](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) is quite easy for some cases. However, there is a [workaround](http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/gprof.html) for threading.